# How can i write spring security without using any role table in database?

Tags: java, sql, spring

I've next classes:

```
class User{
     private int id;
     private String email;
     private String password;
}

class Admin extends User{
     // the same fields as in User class
}

class REDAdmin extends User{
     private String company;
     private String description;
}

class Customers extends User{
     private String FirstName;
     private String LastName;
     ....
}
```

In my db, I don't need any Role table
security-context.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/REDadmin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_REDADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

Comment: How does your configuration look like?

Comment: I'm using hibernate. Table Users must have one-to-one hibernate annotation with Admin, REDadmin and Customers table. I don't know how to configure spring-security.xml and other files.

Comment: Not sure, but think it is not possible. Take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html)

Comment: Oneway to provide the roles is to provide a SQL query, therefore it would been usefull if you could tell us the database structure used by your users, admin,...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZiZTsIESiSVVlNTFVUV1ZSanM/view

Comment: What does your security-config currently look like?

Comment: i don't know how to write authentication-manager and authentication-provider

Answer (score 6):

If you don't require to manage the roles using a relation you could return a fixed set of Roles in your entity classes. A user/account should implement the [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) contract - eg:

```
class User implements UserDetails {

    private final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        // ... add further roles if required
    }

    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    ...
}
```

See: [GrantedAuthority](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html), [SimpleGrantedAuthority](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/authority/SimpleGrantedAuthority.html)